# How Big is Your Vocabulary?

Tags: riddle

Can you guess what I am?

> Sometimes I hang out with the Pope,
>
> Other times I spend my time in the country.
>
> I do not have just one correct spelling, but two.
>
> A botanist would describe me as a shape of a plant.
>
> I can be functional, symbolic, or even someone’s name.

Comment: Good question, dude 

Comment: When a riddle also serves as an introduction / ice breaker

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I know who you are. You are...

> Crozier.

---

"Sometimes I hang out with the Pope"

> A crozier is a kind of religious staff...

"Other times I spend my time in the country."

> ... also known as a pastoral staff

"I do not have just one correct spelling, but two."

> Crosier

"A botanist would describe me as a shape of a plant."

> An unfurling fern.

"I can be functional,"

> The staff as a walking stick

"symbolic, "

> the staff as a symbol

"or even someone’s name."

> Sneaky, sneaky <s>boi</s> gal!

Comment: Haha, very good, this is the correct answer! :D (I am a girl though!)

Comment: AH! that was sneaky! Great riddle.

Comment: Haha thanks and I like the edit @J.Siebeneichler

Answer (score 10):

Is it this?

> miter/mitre

Sometimes I hang out with the Pope,

> [Papal miter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitre#/media/File:Visita_di_Papa_Benedetto_XVI_a_Genova_-_2008-05-18_-_Primo_piano_di_Benedetto_XVI.jpg).

Other times I spend my time in the country.

> Not sure... Could it refer to a [miter snake](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mitre_snake) because those could be found in the country.

I do not have just one correct spelling, but two.

> AmE: *miter*, BrE *mitre*

A botanist would describe me as a shape of a plant.

> "Mitre-shaped" is used in botany, e.g. [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=HVAMAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA541&lpg=PA541&dq=mitre-shaped). Also, in plant names like the [Chilean Mitre Flower](http://www.thegardenhelper.com/mitraria.html).

I can be functional, symbolic, or even someone’s name.

> A [miter shell](https://www.britannica.com/animal/mitre-shell) is functional, as it protects the creature. The religious miter is symbolic. "Mitre" is apparently a name in [Bulgarian and Macedonian](https://www.behindthename.com/name/mitre): "Митре".

Comment: Good try, but incorrect!

Answer (score 8):

I think you're

> Capitalized (or a capitalized word)

Sometimes I hang out with the Pope

> Well Pope is written capitalized

Other times I spend my time in the country.

> Countries are written capitalized

I do not have just one correct spelling, but two.

> Uppercase & capitalized

A botanist would describe me as a shape of a plant.

> When they are described in latin its capitalized.

I can be functional, symbolic, or even someone’s name.

> I think all these are written capitalized.

Comment: Good guess, but incorrect! :)

Answer (score 6):

I'm thinking

> Bell/belle

Sometimes I hang out with the Pope

> I don't know of any specific bells in the Vatican City but I'm sure there must be at least one. Bells also quite literally "hang" from the ceiling.

Other times I spend my time in the country.

> Might refer to the phrase "country belle"

I do not have just one correct spelling, but two.

> See above: bell/belle

A botanist would describe me as a shape of a plant.

> There are a few plants with bell-shaped flowers: bluebells, for instance.

I can be functional, symbolic, or even someone’s name.

> Some bells ring, such as Big Ben; some are just decorative, like the Liberty Bell (I believe); Belle can be a woman's name.

Comment: Good guess, but incorrect!

Answer (score 6):

I think

> Christ

```
Sometimes I hang out with the Pope,
```

> The Pope is the head of the Catholic religion.

```
Other times I spend my time in the country.
```

> All of the believers

```
I do not have just one correct spelling, but two.
```

> Jesus / Christ, where Christ is the title, also treated as a name, given to Jesus of Nazareth - Google dictionary.

```
A botanist would describe me as a shape of a plant.
```

> The [Christ plant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphorbia_milii) (crown of thorns)

```
I can be functional,
```

> Not sure

symbolic,

> the cross

or even someone’s name.

> Christian

Comment: Very good guess, but incorrect! :)

Answer (score 3):

I think it's

> a cross / crucifix

Sometimes I hang out with the Pope

> Well thats obvious

Other times I spend my time in the country.

> cross country

I do not have just one correct spelling, but two.

> cross & crucifix

A botanist would describe me as a shape of a plant.

> cross-formed

I can be functional, symbolic, or even someone’s name.

> cross keys, crucifix in Christianity, Ben Cross

Comment: Good guess again, but incorrect! :)

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> Linden/Lyndon ?

Sometimes I hang out with the Pope,

> Walter Lyndon Pope was a United States federal judge. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walter_Lyndon_Pope)

Other times I spend my time in the country.

> There are many places across the world that are called [Linden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linden) or [Lyndon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyndon)

I do not have just one correct spelling, but two.

> See answer

A botanist would describe me as a shape of a plant.

> Linden is a genus of tree called [Tilia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilia), also known as "lime tree". Its leaves have a (in my opinion) very unique, asymmetrical [shape](http://www.cirrusimage.com/Trees/Ulmaceae/big-leaved_linden_foliage.jpg)

I can be functional, symbolic, or even someone’s name.

> **Functional:** The currency in Second Life is called [Linden Dollars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economy_of_Second_Life)
>   **Symbolic:** The company behind Second Life is called [Linden Lab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linden_Lab)
>   **Name:** Lyndon is a first name

Comment: I don't quite understand your interpretation of the 4th line. How does, what you have written, got to do anything with Shape of plant?

Comment: @Sid edited the 4th point.

Comment: Good guess, but incorrect! @QBrute

Answer (score 2):

I think it's

> Barren/Baron

Sometimes I hang out with the Pope

> A prestigious Baron may hang with the pope

Other times I spend my time in the country.

> A Baron would often spend time in their estate

A botanist would describe me as a shape of a plant

> Perhaps 'shape' is not literal, but the fertility. A Barren plant bears no fruit.

I Can be functional, symbolic, or even someone’s name.

> Both symbolic of prestige, a function of hierarchy, or sometimes a person's name

Comment: Good guess, but incorrect!

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing

> Bear/bare

Sometimes I hang out with the Pope

> Does the pope shit in the woods? The phrase is used in The Big Lebowski, hence question title, but predates the film. Etymology varies depending on location. For me it was always fusion of Does the pope smoke dope? And Does a bear shit in the woods. https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/does_the_Pope_shit_in_the_woods.

Other times I spend my time in the country.

> Bear, Bear Grylls

A botanist would describe me as a shape of a plant

> Bare tree

I can be functional, symbolic, or even someone’s name.

> Bear Grylls, Russian bear, Bare all etc

Comment: I find that phrase (pope) humorous, but you're probably getting down voted because, "what does it have to do with your answer?", i.e. bear/bare. I don't see the botanical state connection as it relates to the original poster's question, which you should restate to make clear what you're answering, because you've technically changed it.

Comment: Added etymology and explanation of title.

Comment: @john changed it. Bit difficult editing on a naff mobile. Is it more clear?

Comment: Yeah, I understand about the mobile. And you've implicitly answered "Other times I spend my time in the country." so I've edited it for you. I don't think it's worthy of downvotes, but that's just me.

Comment: Sorry @Sentinel, creative answer, but incorrect! :)

Comment: @MicCrozier No way! :-)